# Ansible lineinfile module special character

Tags: ansible

When i try to add in sudoers at eof the following file with lineinfile module the special character "!" not added the line any more. Without the special character is added ok.
Any ideea?

ansible 10.x.x.x -m lineinfile -a "path=/etc/sudoers insertafter=EOF line='Defaults:user  !requiretty' validate='/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s' state=present"

Answer (score 0):

Kind of tricky, but works

```
line: "Defaults:user {{ '!' }}requiretty"
```

You can use it in a playbook. One would run short of quotation marks in the command-line .